# CKEditor not working in laravel request

Tags: php, laravel-5, ckeditor

I have a normal `textarea`, and I am initializing `CKeditor` in basic way. The problem is I am unable to get `textarea` POST data in Request Laravel.

```
<textarea cols="80" id="description" name="description" class="" rows="10"></textarea>
```

JS

```
if ($('#description').length) {
    //var ck = $('.ckeditor');
    CKEDITOR.replace('description');
}
```

Now when I try `$request->description`, it returns `NULL`

Comment: please share full html  and controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue and I got it working as follows but I had used `ajax`. Perhaps, this should get you started for what you are looking for:

```
$("form[id='formId']").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }

    var inputData = new FormData($(this)[0]),

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: inputData,
        async: true,
        success: function( res ) {
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get input values like,

```
$request->input('description'); or $request->all();
```